# Initialize UITableview with Contents from XML but can't show progress with UIAlertview

Tags: ios, objective-c, master-detail, uialertcontroller

I am writing an app, which is getting data from the net using XML. It is a master-detail-app which is fetching data for the master-table and after selecting one item from the master-Table it fills the data for the detailview(s) using another network-access.

I would like to present an alert in order to show the user that the app is busy accessing the net or busy calculating. So I would present the view from the `UIAlertController` before the calculation / network access starts and dismiss the view when the activity has completed

Problem is: I don't know where to put this call to show / dismiss the `UIAlertcontroller` view.

Putting the activity code into `ViewWillAppear` shows and dismisses the alertview BEFORE the network-access... Putting everything into `ViewDidLoad` seems not the way to go.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Working"
                                                                   message:@"Working on it"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Accounts"
                                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                           target:nil
                                                                           action:nil];

    NSURL *url;
    if ([self getSession])
    {
        NSMutableString *URLstring = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.xml?session="];

        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        [URLstring appendString:[[DataStore getData]SessionString]];

        url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLstring];
        self.myXXXXXXParserAlleKontenXMLDelegate = [[KontenParserDelegate alloc] init];
        self.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        self.xmlParser.delegate = self.myfxbookParserAlleKontenXMLDelegate;

        if ([self.xmlParser parse])
        {
            [self.objects removeAllObjects];

            for(int i=0; i< [self.XXXXXXXXXrAlleKontenXMLDelegate.allAccounts count];i++)
            {
                [self.objects addObject : [self.myfxbookParserAlleKontenXMLDelegate.allAccounts objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
            NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"name" ascending: YES];
            [self.objects sortUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];

            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }
    }
}
```

**Added** After some discussions I added some new framework "SVProgressHUD" and entered the following code into "ViewWillAppear" where [self parserstuff] contains all the XML parsing..

```
[SVProgressHUD show];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   [self parserstuff];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    });
});
```

This leaves me with a HUD-Display showing up while parsing XML but the resulting Tableview does not show data but is empty...  After switching to DISPATCH_SYNC it works.

Solution would be

1) Put code in ViewDidLoad
2) encapsulate Code between "SVProgressHUD show" and "dismiss" with dispatch_async

as in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [SVProgressHUD show];
    [self parserstuff];
    [self fillComparatorParameters:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
   // }];
});
```

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow.  This isn't a writting code service, you must try write some code and post here in order to we can help you.

Comment: added my ViewWillAppear-approach which gives a message ]" Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <MasterViewController: 0x79996f50>."

Comment: I don't think a UIAlertView is the correct approach, have a look at using something like this https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD

Comment: Added SVProgressHUD, did all the required frameworking and coding stuff (Will enter the snippet in the starter posting). This leaves me with a HUD-Indicator spinning, after that an empty tableview is shown. Looks like that ViewWillAppear is not the right place...

Comment: Well Well, I found that I need dispatch_sync and not dispatch_async. The baby now works... Thanks

Comment: Solution will be posted in the starter post. Thanks for helping me. I am flagging it solved.